# How can I put images in the body of a message in delphi 7?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, indy-9

I am working with sending mails through the smtp protocol using the Indy idMessage object in delphi 7 (therefore the Indy version is 9). I was sending messages in html format without problems, but now I would like to embed an image in the body of the message. I saw that it would not be as easy as putting:

```
<img src='C:\Foo\image.png'>
```

From what I saw, you have to initialize an IdAttachment and reference it in the html, but I couldn't make it work as such.

Next I leave the code used to create the body of the message

```
procedure TfmMail.SendMail;
var
  IdMensaje: TIdMessage;
  smtp: TIdSMTP;
begin
  IdMensaje := TIdMessage.Create(nil);
  IdMensaje.Clear;
  IdMensaje.Body.Clear;
  IdMensaje.ContentType := 'text';
  IdMensaje.From.Text :=  'Title from email';
  IdMensaje.Body.Text := 'greeting';
  IdMensaje.ContentType := 'text/html';
  //<img src='C:\Foo\image.png> -> Don't work
  IdMensaje.Body.Text := IdMensaje.Body.Text + '<p> Other text to body </p>;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generate HTML e-mail with embedded images in Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1569281/generate-html-e-mail-with-embedded-images-in-delphi)

Comment: I had seen this post. But in my case (I think given the version of indy) I don't have access to the ContentID property. Any suggestions for this situation?

Comment: @Lucho "*I am working with ... delphi 7 (therefore the Indy version is 9)*" - why not upgrade to Indy 10? It supports Delphi 7. Your task is so much easier in Indy 10 than in Indy 9. See [HTML Messages](https://www.indyproject.org/2005/08/17/html-messages/) and [New HTML Message Builder class](https://www.indyproject.org/2008/01/16/new-html-message-builder-class/) in Indy's blog. "*I don't have access to the ContentID property*" - then you must be using a MUCH OLDER version of Indy (Indy 8, or maybe an early Indy 9), because `TIdAttachment` DOES have a `ContentID` property in the last Indy 9.

Comment: @Lucho In any case, if you really do not have a `ContentID` property available, you can use the `TIdAttachment`'s `Headers` or `ExtraHeaders` property to set a `Content-ID` header manually.

Answer (score 3):

For Indy 9, you need to:

- set the `TIdMessage.ContentType` property to `multipart/related; type="text/html"`,
- add a `TIdText` object to the `TIdMessage.MessageParts` property (instead of using `TIdMessasage.Body`), containing the HTML content. The HTML's `<img>` tags can refer to each attachment using a `cid:<content-id>` identifier in their `src` attribute.
- add a separate `TIdAttachment` object to `TIdMessage.MessageParts` for each image, and assign a unique `Content-ID` header assigned to each one.

Try something like this:

```
procedure TfmMail.SendMail;
var
  IdMensaje: TIdMessage;
  ...
begin
  IdMensaje := TIdMessage.Create(nil);
  try
    ...

    IdMensaje.ContentType := 'multipart/related; type="text/html"';

    with TIdText.Create(IdMensaje.MessageParts, nil) do
    begin
      ContentType := 'text/html';
      Body.Text := '... <img src="cid:myimageid"> ...';
    end;

    with TIdAttachment.Create(IdMensaje.MessageParts, 'C:\Foo\image.png') do
    begin
      ContentType := 'image/png';

      ContentID := '<myimageid>';
      //
      // or, if ContentID is not available:
      //
      // Headers.Values['Content-ID'] := '<myimageid>';
      // or:
      // ExtraHeaders.Values['Content-ID'] := '<myimageid>';
    end;

    // use IdMensaje as needed ...
  finally
    IdMensaje.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You can either point the `img` tag to an external url (keep in mind that Outlook will block image downloads by default unless the user explicitly clicks on "Download images") or
2. you can add images as attachments, set their `Content-Id` MIME header (e.g. to `'xyz'`) on the attachment MIME part, then refer to that image in the HTML body though that content-id, e.g., `<img src="cid:xyz">`
3. Third option would be embedding image data in the `img` tag, but not all email clients understand that - older versions of Outlook won't render images like that: `<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64, LzlqLzRBQ..." />`